# how to get all wp core functionalities without using wp_head() & wp_footer() in our theme files

Tags: wordpress

I need to get all the core wordpress functionalities in my theme. How could I get this without the use of action hooks like '`wp_head();`' & '`wp_footer();`'

Comment: What functionalities are you want could please give some example functions?

Answer (score 1):

Inside your themes [functions.php](https://codex.wordpress.org/Functions_File_Explained) file you can access, modify and add extra functionality. You can also access the WordPress Globals within your [own functions](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/theme-functions/) like so:

```
global $wpdb, $post;
```

You can access WordPress functionality from outside the installation by including wp-load.php:

```
include('/home/path/public_html/wp-load.php');
```